# Defining access-level based on object's field value

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, shiro

Suppose this class (in groovy):

```
class Class_A {
    String type
    ...
}
```

I want to define access-levels to its instances based on value of type. For example some users would have Read access on Class_A, if type value is "T1" and others have Read access on them, if type value is "T2".
Please don't offer inheritance-based solutions. Can I do it using spring-security or apache shiro?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no plugin which solves this problem out of the box, but I have implemented projects with shiro which do restrict access to objects.

You problem will split up into two separate problems:

a) restrict direct access to objects - users without permissions should not be able to access the show page to those objects

b) filter lists and searches - users without the right permission shouldn't see those objects in the overview list and search results

---

my Solution for a):

create a Filter-Class (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#filters) and add a `before`-filter for each controller which is able to show the objects which are to be secured. Within this filter, you can pre-fetch the object and check the permissions. If they don't match, you can redirect to an access denied page. (Hibernate seems to be smart enough to take you object from the cache when you request it a second time in the controller)

Btw: this way, you can also implement other implicit permissions and roles (e.g. show an object only if user has created it himself)

---

my Solution for b):

In most projects, you have to modify the list views and add a search. So why not simply add a search criteria as filter for the objects? If you use the criteria builder, adding an additional criteria is easy... But you have to make sure that pagination and sorting is done the right way.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Shiro can do this, but it does require a bit of work.

In my solution I implemented a classic RBAC model and provided a custom AuthorizingRealm overriding these methods

```
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principal)
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
```

The AuthorizationInfo that gets returned should contain the Roles and Permissions that a user should have.

```
SimpleAuthorizationInfo authInfo= new SimpleAuthorizationInfo( acl.getRoles() );
authInfo.addStringPermissions( acl.getPermissions() );
return authInfo;
```

In Shiro permissions are defined as:

```
domain:action:instance
```

So in your example this string permissions would allow edits on the T1 instance of Class_A

```
Class_A:edit:T1
```

You can also allow "all" actions or instances.

```
Class_A:*:T1  // allow all actions
      or
Class_A:edit:* // allow edit of all instances
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the job: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl/